# Edit or Add to GIMP's default templates

Tags: resolution, gimp, templates

In GIMP under FIle -> New menu, we have a preset number and resolutions of templates. See image below:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to add new image sizes and resolutions to this list.
I have already tried editing my `~/.gimp-2.8/templaterc` file but that had no effect. Even editing the global one in `/etc/gimp/2.0/` had no effect either.

Then there is a warning on the `~.gimp-2.8` templaterc file: "This file will be entirely rewritten each time you exit."

How can I achieve this in Gimp 2.8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Gimp, click on Windows --> Dockable Dialogs --> Templates

[image]

Once the new window opens you can either create or edit a template.

[image]